cocoapods gem, cannot uninstall old version because lacking permissions on /usr/bin
Apparently at some point I installed cocoapods via sudo gem install cocoapods. This seems to have placed the cocoapods binaries in /usr/bin. It seems at some macOS updated this directory became read only. Now, I would like to remove this old version but when I try to execute sudo gem uninstall cocoapods I get the following error:
Fire:~ root# sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Remove executables:
    pod, sandbox-pod

in addition to the gem? [Yn]
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.

As you can see I've already tried from the root user via sudo -i but to no success. I've also tried disabling SIP and then executing it as root, but alas to no success. Is there any way to remove this folder or a clean installation is the only possibility?

After many unsuccessful attempts I could not find a way to remove stuff that was already installed in /usr/bin. I ended up re-installing macOS to have a clean system since I had a lot of old gems that might interfere with my workflows at some point.
